# Netcat ajax форма заявки

Tags: netcat

дайте пожалуйста пример формы заявки ajax для netcat

Comment: У вас поиск не работает? https://netcat.ru/developers/forum/srch.html?action=index&forum_word=ajax и [в документации](https://netcat.ru/search/?nc_ctpl=833&area=%2Fdevelopers%2Fdocs%2F*&search_query=ajax)

Comment: это всё не то,там нет примеров